# Core-Plot how to format the legends, see picture

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-plot, legend-properties

I have been trying to fix this problem but not been able to do so. I am not able to find any good examples on the web either.

I have tried rowHeightsThatFit: but don't get it to work.

I want to lay out the bottom legends on one line alternative make sure it is seen.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `CPTLegend` [class reference](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_legend.html):

You will want to modify the `numberOfRows` attribute from the layout properties:

> **numberOfRows**: The desired number of rows of legend entries. If zero (0) (the default), the number of rows will be automatically
>   determined. If both numberOfRows and numberOfColumns are greater than
>   zero but their product is less than the total number of legend
>   entries, some entries will not be shown.

And also be careful how you set the `numberOfColumns` property:

> **numberOfColumns**: The desired number of columns of legend entries. If zero (0) (the
>   default), the number of columns will be automatically determined. If
>   both numberOfRows and numberOfColumns are greater than zero but their
>   product is less than the total number of legend entries, some entries
>   will not be shown.

Comment: A BIG thank you :-) I did look at those but for some reason i did not get any effect, this time it did work and you solved my problem (+1)